# A strange thing when using google-http-java-client library api to parser json

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

On Android,I use the google-http-java-client library to parser json from google place api.
I followed  instructions on these website [google-http-java-client-json](http://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/wiki/JSON#Pluggable_Streaming_Library)  and [Android Working with Google Places and Maps Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/)

I get the json content from google place detail search api:

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "result" : {
      "address_components" : [
         {
            "long_name" : "10号",
            "short_name" : "10号",
            "types" : [ "street_number" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "East Chang'an Avenue",
            "short_name" : "East Chang'an Avenue",
            "types" : [ "route" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Dongcheng",
            "short_name" : "Dongcheng",
            "types" : [ "sublocality", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Beijing",
            "short_name" : "Beijing",
            "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Beijing",
            "short_name" : "Beijing",
            "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "CN",
            "short_name" : "CN",
            "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
         }
      ],
      "formatted_address" : "10号 East Chang'an Avenue, Dongcheng, Beijing, China",
      "formatted_phone_number" : "010 6528 8888",
      "geometry" : {
         "location" : {
            "lat" : 39.9074880,
            "lng" : 116.4090440
         }
      },
      "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
      "id" : "33c009586d7d2ac1a8d8392c02f03db6c316710a",
      "international_phone_number" : "+86 10 6528 8888",
      "name" : "Shanggong Law Firm",
      "reference" : "CnRvAAAA25ct_IRN2tU_bHsLhfuwQmvrfRR_WEPvFv30GtadCc6Axe6hK3OkL0B1UrLNu7J2scVzn5qylFTf_YOzhf14ba2GcrkCnGkXeobKxJ-DDUCTJOIqVzuvj1BZ5Vb-OxboQeztU3VI9zBgAFGwe8sg3xIQTxsKMMP88wqEtgmQ3ykp7xoUfXj-wTk2kM9v3aQ65wS3bsn5CI8",
      "types" : [ "lawyer", "establishment" ],
      "url" : "https://plus.google.com/113831070987505202557/about?hl=en-US",
      "utc_offset" : 480,
      "vicinity" : "10号 East Chang'an Avenue, Dongcheng, Beijing",
      "website" : "http://www.splf.com.cn/"
   },
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

the pojo map to this json is

```
public class PoiDetail extends GenericJson implements Serializable{

@Key
public String status;

@Key
public PoiDetailPlace result;

}

public class PoiDetailPlace implements Serializable{

@Key
public String id;

@Key
public String name;

@Key
public String reference;

@Key
public String icon;


@Key
public String vicinity;


@Key
public String formatted_address;
@Key
public String formatted_phone_number;

@Key
public String international_phone_number;


@Key
public String website;
@Key
public Geometry geometry;

public static class Geometry implements Serializable{

    @Key
    public Location location;
}

public static class Location implements Serializable{

    @Key
    public double lat;
    @Key
    public double lng;
}
```

}

Strange thing happen when I write the parser method.
If I write my code like this,it's all right.I can get the detail information:

```
public PoiDetail getPoiDetail(String reference) throws IOException{

    try {
        HttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = createRequestFactory(HTTP_TRANSPORT);
        HttpRequest request = httpRequestFactory
                .buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(DETAILS_SEARCH_URL));
        request.getUrl().put("key", API_KEY);
        request.getUrl().put("reference", reference);
        request.getUrl().put("sensor", "false");
        PoiDetail detail = request.execute().parseAs(PoiDetail.class);
        return detail;
    } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e("Error in Perform Details", e.getMessage());
        throw e;
    }

}
```

If I write code like this,it won't work.When executing "request.execute().parseAs(PoiDetail.class);", it will enter the catch block but give no clue.When I debug,I can't get what the exception is:

```
public PoiDetail getPoiDetail(String reference){

    try {
        HttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = createRequestFactory(HTTP_TRANSPORT);
        HttpRequest request = httpRequestFactory
                .buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(DETAILS_SEARCH_URL));
        request.getUrl().put("key", API_KEY);
        request.getUrl().put("reference", reference);
        request.getUrl().put("sensor", "false");
        PoiDetail detail = request.execute().parseAs(PoiDetail.class);
        return detail;
    } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

}
```

I wonder

**what leads the two method into different result?**

**Why shouldn't I catch the IOException ?**

**What's theory under this?**

Comment: What is the output you are getting in first implementation ? Are you getting Exception or is it printing "Error in Perform Details" ?? I feel that IOException is happening.

Comment: @Deepak In the first implementation ,I get the PoiDetail object with json information in it.I don't get any Exception.

Comment: @Deepak The first implementation just returns what I want.It doesn't print any error information.while in the second situation, it will enter the IOException block but the e object is nothing ,I mean it acts as if the e object is not even instantiated.So I can't even get any stack trace information.

Comment: so in second option; what does  System.out.println ("$$"+e+"$$"); print ?

Comment: @Deepak well,that's is the trick thing here.Any code before the return statement will be ignored as if they were not exist.I add 'Log.v("xx","xx")' and 'int i = 1; System.out.println(i);'before return statement ,none of these ever execute.So the e object is nothing.In debug mode,I can't even watch the e object. I have no idea how it happened .Is this a bug in compiler or VM?

Comment: There is no bug in JVM. We need to identify exception happening at which line. For that put System.out.println (1);System.out.println (2); etc after each line of your above code. So, you might get output of 1,2,3 .. So you know exception happened after printing 3.

Comment: @Deepak yeah,I got it.But the problem is that the System.out.println() statement doesn't work as I said before.Any statement before  return statement in the catch block will just be ignored.So it can't print 1,2,3 or the stack trace and I can't identify the exception specificly. I located that the exception happened in line `PoiDetail detail = request.execute().parseAs(PoiDetail.class);`.But I don't have src of the library,I can't locate the error place any further and deeper.